# Eclipse: An error has occured. See the log file null

Tags: eclipse, macos

I can no longer open **eclipse** anymore after I executed this command `sudo eclipse -clean` in the terminal.
The app runs with root privilege `sudo eclipse`, however I want to run with normal user.
When I execute `eclipse` in the terminal, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing storage.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:251)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTableLock (Permission denied)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:345)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.location.Locker_JavaNio.lock(Locker_JavaNio.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.lock(StorageManager.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getChildStorageManager(Storage.java:2172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getInfoInputStream(Storage.java:2189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:94)
    ... 10 more
```

When I open **eclipse** from **Applications**, I get this error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWVKe.png)

It was running fine until I `sudo eclipse -clean`.

Comment: Looks like you have managed to change the ownership of at least one file in the Eclipse app. I would say you probably need to completely erase Eclipse.app and reinstall from scratch - your workspace should not be affected (but back it up anyway). You should never need to use sudo with Eclipse

Comment: @greg-449 It's working. Thank you.